# Tying multiple conditions IsEmpty Cell.Value and Offset

Tags: vba, offset

I would like to highlight cells that meet a certain set of criteria's.  All cells between columns D through Q are the range that should be effected.

The cell value must equal "y".
The adjacent cell in column S must equal "New row".
The adjacent cell in column A must equal the cell above it.  for example: A2 = A1, A3 = A2, A4 = A3 etc..
and the cell above the cell equaling "y" must be blank.

the order doesn't matter, I suppose.

Please help..

Here is what I've written so far..

```
    Sub TestMod()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:S1000")

For Each cell In rng

If cell.Value = "y" AND IsEmpty(Offset(cell.Value = "y",0,-1)
Then

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
   End If
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


End Sub
```

I've also attached the spreadsheet that I'm working with.

[Attachment](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1_rBzx8PzrYWURVeWVKSUo4OEk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a "not-conditional formatting" approach as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range, newRowRng As Range, myRow As Range, f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Sheets("myDataSheetName") '<--| change "myDataSheetName" to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A1", .cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:S range from row 1 (header) down to the one corresponding to last column S not empty row
            FormatDefault .cells '<--| set all range cells to their "default" format
            .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="New row" '<--| filter column S cells with "New row"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then Set newRowRng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| if any filtered cells other than headers then set 'newRowRng' to them
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter
        End With

        If newRowRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<--| if no "newRow" in column S then exit sub

        For Each myRow In Intersect(newRowRng, .Columns(1)) '<--| loop through column A "filtered" cells
            If myRow.Value = myRow.Offset(-1).Value Then '<--| if current cell value equals the one above
                With Intersect(newRowRng, myRow.EntireRow) '<--| reference current cell entire data row
                    Set f = .Find(what:="y", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<--| search it for "y"
                    If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if found
                        firstAddress = f.Address '<--| store first found cell address
                        Do '<--| start a loop
                            If Len(f.Offset(-1)) = 0 Then FormatCell f '<--| if empty cell above current found cell thne set this latter format
                            Set f = .FindNext(f) '<--| search for the next "y"
                        Loop While Not f.Address = firstAddress '<--| exit whne 'Find()' wraps back to first found cell
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Sub FormatDefault(rng As Range)
    With rng
        With .Font
            .Color = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Interior
            .Color = 16777215
            .PatternColorIndex = -4142
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub FormatCell(rng As Range)
    With rng
        With .Font
            .Color = -16383844
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 13551615
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this solves your question then please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. I always tend to avoid Conditional Formatting since it eventually leads me to big and without control files